# Boto does not save s3 file to disc on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto

I'm working on a module that gets information about a sequence of images from my MySQL database and then downloads them locally on Lambda using the boto library.  Afterwards, it should do some image processing, but I'm not quite there yet.

The error I keep getting is strange.  After (I believe) it downloads the first image, it says it does not exist as a file/directory:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/module.py", line 41, in lambda_handler key.get_contents_to_filename(string) 

File "/var/task/boto/s3/key.py", line 1714, in get_contents_to_filename os.remove(filename) OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.png'
```

Line 41 in my code is found here:

```
# Download and Save all of the cropped images for this company  
count = 1
files_list = []
for image in cropped_images:
    key = bucket.get_key(image)
    string = str(count) + '.png'
    key.get_contents_to_filename(string)
    files_list.append(string) 
    count += 1
print("should be done downloading all of the pictures from S3 ...")
```

Here's the full script for the module that I have so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json, os
import pymysql

import os, glob, subprocess, boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = pymysql.connect(host='*******', port=3306, user='*****', passwd='******', db='*******')
cur = conn.cursor()

conn = S3Connection('***************','************************')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('**********')

def upload_file(company_friendly, filepath):
    key = bucket.new_key(company_friendly + ".gif")
    key.set_contents_from_filename(filepath)
    key.set_acl('public-read')
    return True

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ### Grab Company Friendly from DB ###
    cur.execute("SELECT ************ FROM *********** WHERE company_id = %i LIMIT 1" % (event['company_id']))

    company_data = cur.fetchone()
    company_friendly = company_data[0]

    ### Grab all snapshots from DB ###
    cur.execute("SELECT *********** FROM ************ WHERE company_id = %i ORDER BY date ASC" % (event['company_id']))
    snapshot_data = cur.fetchall()  

    cropped_images = []
    for snapshot in snapshot_data:
        cropped_images.append(snapshot[0])

    ### Download and Save all of the cropped images for this company  ###
    count = 1
    files_list = []
    for image in cropped_images:
        key = bucket.get_key(image)
        string = str(count) + '.png'
        key.get_contents_to_filename(string)
        files_list.append(string) #this makes sure that the animated gif compiles the images in order
        count += 1
    print("should be done downloading all of the pictures from S3 ...")

    return(json.dumps({'status_code':200, 'msg':"company friendly name is " + company_friendly}, sort_keys=True))
```

Any ideas why it isn't saving the image files? I am using the default S3 role suggested by the Lambda console

Comment: Can you try changing the line to: string = '/tmp/' + str(count) + '.png'

Comment: That sorted it right out - thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing the line to:

`string = '/tmp/' + str(count) + '.png'`

There is no way to know if you have write access in current dir on a lambda machine. But `/tmp` will let you write.

From: [AWS Lambda FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)

> Q: What if I need scratch space on disk for my AWS Lambda function?
>
> Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space in
>   its own /tmp directory.

Comment: Is there a link for Lambda documentation where I can find information like this?

Comment: "Q: What if I need scratch space on disk for my AWS Lambda function?

Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space in its own /tmp directory."

[source](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)

Comment: Thanks @buildmaestro. I updated my answer. The FAQ was not there when the question was asked.